# minAjax is not defined - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, api

sinceramente les vengo a escribir sin muchas posibilidades de poder probar otro camino. Estoy aprendiendo en un curso y debo entregar un proyecto utilizando exactamente el **mismo** método y camino que les voy a pasar a detallar posteriormente, por lo tanto **no hay otra forma** de que la que se me plantea en el curso en la que poder resolver este problema.
La cuestión es con la librería minAjax.js que estamos aprendiendo a utilizar. De hecho, es para introducirnos a Ajax y consumir Apis. La cuestión es que aunque siga paso a paso lo que me aparece en el video, en el momento que quiero utilizar la función "minAjax" dentro de un archivo js, me aparece que no está definido. Se muy bien que no está definido dentro de ese archivo, pero sucede lo mismo en el video del curso y pueden usar la función automaticamente como si ya estuviese importado.

Les paso a detallar el código HTML primero:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flouthoc/minAjax.js/master/index.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora les paso a detallar lo que hay dentro del arhivo que estoy importando, el de Ajax, el "index.js". El código dice lo siguiente (viene por defecto de la página, esto es lo que te aparece):

```
/*|--minAjax.js--|
  |--(A Minimalistic Pure JavaScript Header for Ajax POST/GET Request )--|
  |--Author : flouthoc (gunnerar7@gmail.com)(http://github.com/flouthoc)--|
  |--Contributers : Add Your Name Below--|
  */
function initXMLhttp() {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //code for IE7,firefox chrome and above
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        //code for Internet Explorer
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}

function minAjax(config) {

    /*Config Structure
            url:"reqesting URL"
            type:"GET or POST"
            method: "(OPTIONAL) True for async and False for Non-async | By default its Async"
            debugLog: "(OPTIONAL)To display Debug Logs | By default it is false"
            data: "(OPTIONAL) another Nested Object which should contains reqested Properties in form of Object Properties"
            success: "(OPTIONAL) Callback function to process after response | function(data,status)"
    */

    if (!config.url) {

        if (config.debugLog == true)
            console.log("No Url!");
        return;

    }

    if (!config.type) {

        if (config.debugLog == true)
            console.log("No Default type (GET/POST) given!");
        return;

    }

    if (!config.method) {
        config.method = true;
    }


    if (!config.debugLog) {
        config.debugLog = false;
    }

    var xmlhttp = initXMLhttp();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            if (config.success) {
                config.success(xmlhttp.responseText, xmlhttp.readyState);
            }

            if (config.debugLog == true)
                console.log("SuccessResponse");
            if (config.debugLog == true)
                console.log("Response Data:" + xmlhttp.responseText);

        } else {

            if (config.debugLog == true)
                console.log("FailureResponse --> State:" + xmlhttp.readyState + "Status:" + xmlhttp.status);
          
            if(config.errorCallback){
                console.log("Calling Error Callback");
                config.errorCallback();
            }
        }
    }

    var sendString = [],
        sendData = config.data;
    if( typeof sendData === "string" ){
        var tmpArr = String.prototype.split.call(sendData,'&');
        for(var i = 0, j = tmpArr.length; i < j; i++){
            var datum = tmpArr[i].split('=');
            sendString.push(encodeURIComponent(datum[0]) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(datum[1]));
        }
    }else if( typeof sendData === 'object' && !( sendData instanceof String || (FormData && sendData instanceof FormData) ) ){
        for (var k in sendData) {
            var datum = sendData[k];
            if( Object.prototype.toString.call(datum) == "[object Array]" ){
                for(var i = 0, j = datum.length; i < j; i++) {
                        sendString.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "[]=" + encodeURIComponent(datum[i]));
                }
            }else{
                sendString.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(datum));
            }
        }
    }
    sendString = sendString.join('&');

    if (config.type == "GET") {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", config.url + "?" + sendString, config.method);
        xmlhttp.send();

        if (config.debugLog == true)
            console.log("GET fired at:" + config.url + "?" + sendString);
    }
    if (config.type == "POST") {
        xmlhttp.open("POST", config.url, config.method);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(sendString);

        if (config.debugLog == true)
            console.log("POST fired at:" + config.url + " || Data:" + sendString);
    }




}
```

Bien, y por último, en el **script.js** (que es el archivo javascript que quiero usar para importar el API). No escribí más nada que esto:

```
minAjax({
 url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
 type: "GET",
 success: function (datosDelServidor) {
 console.log(datosDelServidor);
 }
})
```

El error que me aparece es: ***""minAjax" is not defined"***, lo cual entiendo, porque de alguna forma la función dentro de ese archivo no está definida aunque esté importada en el html, sin embargo en el video del curso funciona correctamente y hasta pudo importar el API que aparece en la URL.

Espero que puedan brindarme una ayuda, es **obligatorio** que use minAjax xq sino **no** es válido, o sea, otro camino **no** está permitido.

Muchas gracias y disculpen la extensión. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segun parece directamente no puedes hacerlo, porque envia un tipo de datos "text/plain" y porque su servidor tiene una cabecera nosniff (que no puedes modificar pues no es tu servidor). Este es el error que se muestra en consola al intentarlo:

> The resource from
> “https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flouthoc/minAjax.js/master/index.js”
> was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Como posible solución puedes usar esto en su lugar:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/flouthoc/minAjax.js@master/index.js"></script>
```

pues [jsdelivr.net](https://www.jsdelivr.com/?docs=gh) permite la invocación de archivos de github de este modo:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/user/repo@version/file
```

Otra solución es descargarte ese archivo en tu servidor web y cargarlo desde allí.

Ejemplo:

```js
minAjax({
 url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
 type: "GET",
 success: function (datosDelServidor) {
 console.log(datosDelServidor);
 }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/flouthoc/minAjax.js@master/index.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sigue sin poder funcionarme, no entiendo por qué,  probé bajando el archivo y usando el link directo de la página. Me preocupa no poder usarlo para el proyecto, no comprendo bien por qué puede ser.

Comment: @JuanAndrés Te acabo de agregar un ejemplo para que veas que funciona (ejecútalo).  Revisa bien los cambios que hayas hecho porque debería funcionarte bien (como aquí)

Comment: me anduvo perfecto, vi que al final el problema es cuando ejecuto el comando en el pluguín quokka, ahí me aparece que no está definida pero me anda perfectamente en el navegador cuando lo ejecuto, no se nada de back-end pero me imagino que tiene que ver con eso. ¡Muchas gracias!